# Was Nina Simone really refused admission to Julliard on racial grounds even though she passed the audition?

Tags: history

I recently watched the movie 'Green Book'. While I was watching it I was reminded of someone who once told me that Nina Simone was refused entry to Julliard on racial grounds. Is this accurate and if so has Julliard ever had any official response to this potentially less-than-savoury part of their past?

We may think that we in the liberal arts sphere are a bit more liberal than, but it is unfortunate to learn that the liberal arts schools were unfortunately not immune to the prejudices of the day.

I personally have no ideological drum to beat, I'm just wondering how segregated the arts really was at one stage in time?

Comment: This question may be suited to the academic.SE. I await assistance from a mod.

Comment: Neil - I'm unsure. I feel it is not quite on topic here or on academic.SE - possibly skeptics.SE is the best place. Let's see whether votes come in on migrating it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it makes sense for skeptics.se to verify a claim and does not seem to be about music practice or theory.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an excellent fit for Music Fans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nina Simone enrolled at Juillard, but was turned down by the Curtis Institute.

According to Wikipedia:

> She applied for a scholarship to study at the Curtis Institute of Music in Philadelphia, where she was denied admission despite a well-received audition, which she attributed to racial discrimination. In 2003, just days before her death, the Institute awarded her an honorary degree.

It wasn't neccessarily racism. According to an [article](https://www.inquirer.com/philly/entertainment/arts/20150816_Curtis_and_the_case_of_Nina_Simone.html) in the Philadelphia Enquirer, Curtis had been admitting Black students for years. It's more likely that she wasn't good enough (the year she applied they only accepted three out of 72 applications)..